# Marker clustering with google maps SDK for iOS?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am using Google Maps SDK in my iOS app, and I need to group markers which are very close to each other - basically need to use marker clustering like its shown in the attached url. I am able to get this functionality in the Android maps SDK, but I didn't find any library for the iOS Google Maps SDK.

Can you please suggest any library for this? **Or** suggest a way to implement a custom library for this?

[image: Marker_Clusterer_Full.png]

([Source](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers?hl=da&csw=1) of this picture)

Comment: Curious if the google SDK better than the MapKit one...

Comment: It is also curious (sarcasm and irony) that currently this feature has been implemented in the Android Google Maps SDK and not in the iOS Google Maps SDK. What a coincidence LOL.

Comment: I have implemented the same app (about 500 pins on map) first in Apple Maps then switched to Google Maps! results: even if I used the same 1 KB gif image for pin image for google maps it was slow as hell -> Apple maps kicks ass in performance, because of the dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier function that google maps does not have!

Answer (score 27):

To understand the underlying concept of this double map solution, please have a look at this [WWDC 2011 video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/111/) (from 22'30). The Map kit code is directly extracted from this video except a few things that I described in a few notes. The Google Map SDK solution is just an adaptation.

**Main idea**: a map is hidden and holds every single annotation, including the merged ones (`allAnnotationMapView` in my code). Another is visible and shows only the cluster's annotations or the annotation if it's single (mapView in my code).

**Second main idea**: I divide the visible map (plus a margin) into squares, and every annotation in a specific square are merged into one annotation.

The code I use for Google Maps SDK (Please note that I wrote this when `markers` property were available on GMSMapView class. It's not anymore but you can keep track of all the marker you add in your own array, and use this array instead of calling mapView.markers):

```c
- (void)loadView {
    [super loadView];
    self.mapView =  [[GMSMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    self.mapView.delegate = self;
    self.allAnnotationMapView = [[GMSMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame]; // can't be zero or you'll have weard results (I don't remember exactly why)
    self.view = self.mapView;
    UIPinchGestureRecognizer* pinchRecognizer = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didZoom:)];
    [pinchRecognizer setDelegate:self];
    [self.mapView addGestureRecognizer:pinchRecognizer];
}

- (void)didZoom:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer {
    if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
        [self updateVisibleAnnotations];
    }
}

- (float)distanceFrom:(CGPoint)point1 to:(CGPoint)point2 {
    CGFloat xDist = (point2.x - point1.x);
    CGFloat yDist = (point2.y - point1.y);
    return sqrt((xDist * xDist) + (yDist * yDist));
}

- (NSSet *)annotationsInRect:(CGRect)rect forMapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView {
    GMSProjection *projection = self.mapView.projection; //always take self.mapView because it is the only one zoomed on screen
    CLLocationCoordinate2D southWestCoordinates = [projection coordinateForPoint:CGPointMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y + rect.size.height)];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D northEastCoordinates = [projection coordinateForPoint:CGPointMake(rect.origin.x + rect.size.width, rect.origin.y)];
    NSMutableSet *annotations = [NSMutableSet set];
    for (GMSMarker *marker in mapView.markers) {
        if (marker.position.latitude < southWestCoordinates.latitude || marker.position.latitude >= northEastCoordinates.latitude) {
            continue;
        }
        if (marker.position.longitude < southWestCoordinates.longitude || marker.position.longitude >= northEastCoordinates.longitude) {
            continue;
        }
        [annotations addObject:marker.userData];
    }
    return annotations;
}

- (GMSMarker *)viewForAnnotation:(PointMapItem *)item forMapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView{
    for (GMSMarker *marker in mapView.markers) {
        if (marker.userData == item) {
            return marker;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}

- (void)updateVisibleAnnotations {
    static float marginFactor = 1.0f;
    static float bucketSize = 100.0f;
    CGRect visibleMapRect = self.view.frame;
    CGRect adjustedVisibleMapRect = CGRectInset(visibleMapRect, -marginFactor * visibleMapRect.size.width, -marginFactor * visibleMapRect.size.height);

    double startX = CGRectGetMinX(adjustedVisibleMapRect);
    double startY = CGRectGetMinY(adjustedVisibleMapRect);
    double endX = CGRectGetMaxX(adjustedVisibleMapRect);
    double endY = CGRectGetMaxY(adjustedVisibleMapRect);
    CGRect gridMapRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, bucketSize, bucketSize);
    gridMapRect.origin.y = startY;
    while(CGRectGetMinY(gridMapRect) <= endY) {
        gridMapRect.origin.x = startX;
        while (CGRectGetMinX(gridMapRect) <= endX) {
            NSSet *allAnnotationsInBucket = [self annotationsInRect:gridMapRect forMapView:self.allAnnotationMapView];
            NSSet *visibleAnnotationsInBucket = [self annotationsInRect:gridMapRect forMapView:self.mapView];
            NSMutableSet *filteredAnnotationsInBucket = [[allAnnotationsInBucket objectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, BOOL *stop) {
                BOOL isPointMapItem = [obj isKindOfClass:[PointMapItem class]];
                BOOL shouldBeMerged = NO;
                if (isPointMapItem) {
                    PointMapItem *pointItem = (PointMapItem *)obj;
                    shouldBeMerged = pointItem.shouldBeMerged;
                }
                return shouldBeMerged;
            }] mutableCopy];
            NSSet *notMergedAnnotationsInBucket = [allAnnotationsInBucket objectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, BOOL *stop) {
                BOOL isPointMapItem = [obj isKindOfClass:[PointMapItem class]];
                BOOL shouldBeMerged = NO;
                if (isPointMapItem) {
                    PointMapItem *pointItem = (PointMapItem *)obj;
                    shouldBeMerged = pointItem.shouldBeMerged;
                }
                return isPointMapItem && !shouldBeMerged;
            }];
            for (PointMapItem *item in notMergedAnnotationsInBucket) {
                [self addAnnotation:item inMapView:self.mapView animated:NO];
            }

            if(filteredAnnotationsInBucket.count > 0) {
                PointMapItem *annotationForGrid = (PointMapItem *)[self annotationInGrid:gridMapRect usingAnnotations:filteredAnnotationsInBucket];
                [filteredAnnotationsInBucket removeObject:annotationForGrid];
                annotationForGrid.containedAnnotations = [filteredAnnotationsInBucket allObjects];
                [self removeAnnotation:annotationForGrid inMapView:self.mapView];
                [self addAnnotation:annotationForGrid inMapView:self.mapView animated:NO];
                if (filteredAnnotationsInBucket.count > 0){
                //                    [self.mapView deselectAnnotation:annotationForGrid animated:NO];
                }
                for (PointMapItem *annotation in filteredAnnotationsInBucket) {
                //                    [self.mapView deselectAnnotation:annotation animated:NO];
                    annotation.clusterAnnotation = annotationForGrid;
                    annotation.containedAnnotations = nil;
                    if ([visibleAnnotationsInBucket containsObject:annotation]) {
                        CLLocationCoordinate2D actualCoordinate = annotation.coordinate;
                        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
                            annotation.coordinate = annotation.clusterAnnotation.coordinate;
                        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                            annotation.coordinate = actualCoordinate;
                            [self removeAnnotation:annotation inMapView:self.mapView];
                        }];
                    }
                }
            }
            gridMapRect.origin.x += bucketSize;
        }
        gridMapRect.origin.y += bucketSize;
    }
}

- (PointMapItem *)annotationInGrid:(CGRect)gridMapRect usingAnnotations:(NSSet *)annotations {
    NSSet *visibleAnnotationsInBucket = [self annotationsInRect:gridMapRect forMapView:self.mapView];
    NSSet *annotationsForGridSet = [annotations objectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, BOOL *stop) {
        BOOL returnValue = ([visibleAnnotationsInBucket containsObject:obj]);
        if (returnValue) {
            *stop = YES;
        }
        return returnValue;
    }];

    if (annotationsForGridSet.count != 0) {
        return [annotationsForGridSet anyObject];
    }

    CGPoint centerMapPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(gridMapRect), CGRectGetMidY(gridMapRect));
    NSArray *sortedAnnotations = [[annotations allObjects] sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {
        CGPoint mapPoint1 = [self.mapView.projection pointForCoordinate:((PointMapItem *)obj1).coordinate];
        CGPoint mapPoint2 = [self.mapView.projection pointForCoordinate:((PointMapItem *)obj2).coordinate];

        CLLocationDistance distance1 = [self distanceFrom:mapPoint1 to:centerMapPoint];
        CLLocationDistance distance2 = [self distanceFrom:mapPoint2 to:centerMapPoint];

        if (distance1 < distance2) {
            return NSOrderedAscending;
        }
        else if (distance1 > distance2) {
            return NSOrderedDescending;
        }
        return NSOrderedSame;
    }];
    return [sortedAnnotations objectAtIndex:0];
    return nil;
}


- (void)addAnnotation:(PointMapItem *)item inMapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView {
    [self addAnnotation:item inMapView:mapView animated:YES];
}

- (void)addAnnotation:(PointMapItem *)item inMapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView animated:(BOOL)animated {
    GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    GMSMarkerAnimation animation = kGMSMarkerAnimationNone;
    if (animated) {
        animation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop;
    }
    marker.appearAnimation = animation;
    marker.title = item.title;
    marker.icon = [[AnnotationsViewUtils getInstance] imageForItem:item];
    marker.position = item.coordinate;
    marker.map = mapView;
    marker.userData = item;
    //    item.associatedMarker = marker;
}

- (void)addAnnotations:(NSArray *)items inMapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView {
    [self addAnnotations:items inMapView:mapView animated:YES];
}

- (void)addAnnotations:(NSArray *)items inMapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView animated:(BOOL)animated {
    for (PointMapItem *item in items) {
        [self addAnnotation:item inMapView:mapView];
    }
}

- (void)removeAnnotation:(PointMapItem *)item inMapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView {
    // Try to make that work because it avoid loopigng through all markers each time we just want to delete one...
    // Plus, your associatedMarker property should be weak to avoid memory cycle because userData hold strongly the item
    //    GMSMarker *marker = item.associatedMarker;
    //    marker.map = nil;
    for (GMSMarker *marker in mapView.markers) {
        if (marker.userData == item) {
            marker.map = nil;
        }
    }
}

- (void)removeAnnotations:(NSArray *)items inMapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView {
    for (PointMapItem *item in items) {
        [self removeAnnotation:item inMapView:mapView];
    }
}
```

A few notes:

- `PointMapItem` is my annotation data class (`id<MKAnnotation>` if we were working with Map kit).
- Here I use a `shouldBeMerged` property on `PointMapItem` because there are some annotations I don't want to merge. If you do not need this, remove the part that is using it or set `shouldBeMerged` to YES for all your annotations. Though, you should probably keep the class testing if you don't want to merge user location!
- When you want to add annotations, add them to the hidden `allAnnotationMapView` and call `updateVisibleAnnotation`. `updateVisibleAnnotation` method is responsible for choosing which annotations to merge and which to show. It will then add the annotation to `mapView` which is visible.

For Map Kit I use the following code:

```c
- (void)didZoom:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer {
    if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
        [self updateVisibleAnnotations];
    }
}
- (void)updateVisibleAnnotations {
    static float marginFactor = 2.0f;
    static float bucketSize = 50.0f;
    MKMapRect visibleMapRect = [self.mapView visibleMapRect];
    MKMapRect adjustedVisibleMapRect = MKMapRectInset(visibleMapRect, -marginFactor * visibleMapRect.size.width, -marginFactor * visibleMapRect.size.height);

    CLLocationCoordinate2D leftCoordinate = [self.mapView convertPoint:CGPointZero toCoordinateFromView:self.view];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D rightCoordinate = [self.mapView convertPoint:CGPointMake(bucketSize, 0) toCoordinateFromView:self.view];
    double gridSize = MKMapPointForCoordinate(rightCoordinate).x - MKMapPointForCoordinate(leftCoordinate).x;
    MKMapRect gridMapRect = MKMapRectMake(0, 0, gridSize, gridSize);

    double startX = floor(MKMapRectGetMinX(adjustedVisibleMapRect) / gridSize) * gridSize;
    double startY = floor(MKMapRectGetMinY(adjustedVisibleMapRect) / gridSize) * gridSize;
    double endX = floor(MKMapRectGetMaxX(adjustedVisibleMapRect) / gridSize) * gridSize;
    double endY = floor(MKMapRectGetMaxY(adjustedVisibleMapRect) / gridSize) * gridSize;

    gridMapRect.origin.y = startY;
    while(MKMapRectGetMinY(gridMapRect) <= endY) {
        gridMapRect.origin.x = startX;
        while (MKMapRectGetMinX(gridMapRect) <= endX) {
            NSSet *allAnnotationsInBucket = [self.allAnnotationMapView annotationsInMapRect:gridMapRect];
            NSSet *visibleAnnotationsInBucket = [self.mapView annotationsInMapRect:gridMapRect];

            NSMutableSet *filteredAnnotationsInBucket = [[allAnnotationsInBucket objectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, BOOL *stop) {
                BOOL isPointMapItem = [obj isKindOfClass:[PointMapItem class]];
                BOOL shouldBeMerged = NO;
                if (isPointMapItem) {
                    PointMapItem *pointItem = (PointMapItem *)obj;
                    shouldBeMerged = pointItem.shouldBeMerged;
                }
                return shouldBeMerged;
            }] mutableCopy];
            NSSet *notMergedAnnotationsInBucket = [allAnnotationsInBucket objectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, BOOL *stop) {
                BOOL isPointMapItem = [obj isKindOfClass:[PointMapItem class]];
                BOOL shouldBeMerged = NO;
                if (isPointMapItem) {
                    PointMapItem *pointItem = (PointMapItem *)obj;
                    shouldBeMerged = pointItem.shouldBeMerged;
                }
                return isPointMapItem && !shouldBeMerged;
            }];
            for (PointMapItem *item in notMergedAnnotationsInBucket) {
                [self.mapView addAnnotation:item];
            }

            if(filteredAnnotationsInBucket.count > 0) {
                PointMapItem *annotationForGrid = (PointMapItem *)[self annotationInGrid:gridMapRect usingAnnotations:filteredAnnotationsInBucket];
                [filteredAnnotationsInBucket removeObject:annotationForGrid];
                annotationForGrid.containedAnnotations = [filteredAnnotationsInBucket allObjects];
                [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotationForGrid];
                //force reload of the image because it's not done if annotationForGrid is already present in the bucket!!
                MKAnnotationView* annotationView = [self.mapView viewForAnnotation:annotationForGrid];
                NSString *imageName = [AnnotationsViewUtils imageNameForItem:annotationForGrid selected:NO];
                UILabel *countLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 2, 8, 8)];
                [countLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:POINT_FONT_NAME size:10]];
                [countLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
                [annotationView addSubview:countLabel];
                imageName = [AnnotationsViewUtils imageNameForItem:annotationForGrid selected:NO];
                annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];

                if (filteredAnnotationsInBucket.count > 0){
                    [self.mapView deselectAnnotation:annotationForGrid animated:NO];
                }
                for (PointMapItem *annotation in filteredAnnotationsInBucket) {
                    [self.mapView deselectAnnotation:annotation animated:NO];
                    annotation.clusterAnnotation = annotationForGrid;
                    annotation.containedAnnotations = nil;
                    if ([visibleAnnotationsInBucket containsObject:annotation]) {
                        CLLocationCoordinate2D actualCoordinate = annotation.coordinate;
                        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
                            annotation.coordinate = annotation.clusterAnnotation.coordinate;
                        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                            annotation.coordinate = actualCoordinate;
                            [self.mapView removeAnnotation:annotation];
                        }];
                    }
                }
            }
            gridMapRect.origin.x += gridSize;
        }
        gridMapRect.origin.y += gridSize;
    }
}

- (id<MKAnnotation>)annotationInGrid:(MKMapRect)gridMapRect usingAnnotations:(NSSet *)annotations {
    NSSet *visibleAnnotationsInBucket = [self.mapView annotationsInMapRect:gridMapRect];
    NSSet *annotationsForGridSet = [annotations objectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, BOOL *stop) {
        BOOL returnValue = ([visibleAnnotationsInBucket containsObject:obj]);
        if (returnValue) {
            *stop = YES;
        }
        return returnValue;
    }];

    if (annotationsForGridSet.count != 0) {
        return [annotationsForGridSet anyObject];
    }
    MKMapPoint centerMapPoint = MKMapPointMake(MKMapRectGetMinX(gridMapRect), MKMapRectGetMidY(gridMapRect));
    NSArray *sortedAnnotations = [[annotations allObjects] sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {
        MKMapPoint mapPoint1 = MKMapPointForCoordinate(((id<MKAnnotation>)obj1).coordinate);
        MKMapPoint mapPoint2 = MKMapPointForCoordinate(((id<MKAnnotation>)obj2).coordinate);

        CLLocationDistance distance1 = MKMetersBetweenMapPoints(mapPoint1, centerMapPoint);
        CLLocationDistance distance2 = MKMetersBetweenMapPoints(mapPoint2, centerMapPoint);

        if (distance1 < distance2) {
            return NSOrderedAscending;
        }
        else if (distance1 > distance2) {
            return NSOrderedDescending;
        }
        return NSOrderedSame;
    }];
    return [sortedAnnotations objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Both should work fine, but if you have any question, feel free to ask!

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing this! Took me a bit to figure out what the PointMapItem should look like exactly. In case somebody else is wondering: https://gist.github.com/plu/b3835e6afe7538fada15

Comment: For future readers: please note that I wrote this when `markers` property were available on GMSMapView class. It's not anymore on recent version of the SDK. But you can keep track of all the markers you add by putting them in your own array, and use this array instead of calling mapView.markers.

Comment: Can I use KMPointMapItem Class https://gist.github.com/plu/b3835e6afe7538fada15 instead of PointMapItem ?

Comment: @Aurelien Porte Adding comments in your code could have been really helpful for people who will try to understand and use it, nonetheless thank you for having shared your source code with the community.

Comment: Can you add the `PointMapItem` class you reference above? I'm not able to get this to work..

Comment: Many questions above left unaswered @AurelienPorte Would you link us to missing classes such as PointMapItem?

Answer (score 20):

After long hours of research, I have finally found a wonderful guy who did this.

Thanks a lot to you **DDRBoxman**.

Check his github : https://github.com/DDRBoxman/google-maps-ios-utils

He recently pushed some code sample.

When I wanted to run his project, I had some issues. I just deleted the Google Maps SDK and follow the complete Google tutorial to integrate Google Maps SDK. Then, no more issues, I was able to run the app.
Don't forget to put your API KEY in the AppDelegate.m.

I will work with this lib for the following days, I will let you know if I find some bugs.

**EDIT #1** : I worked a lot on clusters these days. My final approach is to integrate an MKMapView, create the cluster on an MKMapView (way much easier than doing it on the Google Maps SDK for iOS) and integrate Google Maps Places to my iOS project.
The performance are better with this approach than the previous one.

**EDIT #2** : I don't know if you use Realm or if you plan to use it but they provide a really good solution for map clustering : https://realm.io/news/building-an-ios-clustered-map-view-in-objective-c/

Comment: I have huge lags on this after each redraw. Like 2 seconds lag. Not really usable. That is on iPhone 4s

Comment: Yes as I said in my edit#1, I stopped working with google maps for clustering. It's really faster to use MKMapView with Google Places API.

Comment: Cool work! Really a good job of Google Map. This project provide a usable prototype to do map clustering. You can change its cluster renderer algorithm to improve the performance. For my modification, I just render the clusters inside or near the map view port instead of rendering all clusters.

Comment: how to distinguish tap on marker between tap on cluster? why `[clusterManager_.items count]` is always 0?

Comment: I wanted to check if cluterManager items contains spot(marker) of marker which was tapped, but it seems empt `[clusterManager_.items count]` is always 0..

Comment: @yalight You mean you show only those clusters which are to be shown in the map area visible at that moment to user right? if yes, could please tell me how did you accomplish this? Thanks

Comment: @andi I don't know if there's an actual method to distinguish between a cluster and a single marker using this library, however I've implemented a work around for this by comparing the `marker.icon.size` in `didTapMarker` delegate method. Assuming the clustered marker size would be a little different in dimensions as compared to the normal marker size.

Comment: What do you use to create the cluster on MKMapView?

Comment: It's been a while since I didn't use clusters. For the "Place To Be" app (available on the iPhone App Store) I used [OCMapView](https://github.com/yinkou/OCMapView). It works very well for my need.

Answer (score 2):

i have an app handle this issue, below is the code

1. loop all markers (nsdictionary) in an array
2. use gmsmapview.projection to get CGPoint in order to find out whether the marker should group together

3 i use 100 points to test and the response time is quite satisfied.

4 the map will redraw if the zoom level difference is over 0.5;

```
  -(float)distance :(CGPoint)pointA point:(CGPoint) pointB{

        return sqrt( (pow((pointA.x - pointB.x),2) + pow((pointA.y-pointB.y),2)));

    }




    -(void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didChangeCameraPosition:(GMSCameraPosition *)position{

        float currentZoomLevel = mapView.camera.zoom;

        if (fabs(currentZoomLevel- lastZoomLevel_)>0.5){

            lastZoomLevel_ = currentZoomLevel;

            markersGroupArray_ = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

            for (NSDictionary *photo in photoArray_){

                float coordx = [[photo objectForKey:@"coordx"]floatValue];
                float coordy = [[photo objectForKey:@"coordy"] floatValue];

                CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(coordx, coordy);

                CGPoint currentPoint = [mapView.projection pointForCoordinate:coord];

                if ([markersGroupArray_ count] == 0){

                    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:photo, nil];

                    [markersGroupArray_ addObject:array];

                }
                else{

                    bool flag_groupadded = false;

                    int counter= 0;
                    for (NSMutableArray *array in markersGroupArray_){

                        for (NSDictionary *marker in array){

                            float mcoordx = [[marker objectForKey:@"coordx"]floatValue];
                            float mcoordy = [[marker objectForKey:@"coordy"]floatValue];

                            CLLocationCoordinate2D mcoord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(mcoordx, mcoordy);
                            CGPoint mpt = [mapView.projection pointForCoordinate:mcoord];

                            if ([self distance:mpt point:currentPoint] <30){
                                flag_groupadded = YES;
                                break;
                            }


                        }
                        if (flag_groupadded){

                            break;
                        }
                        counter++;

                    }


                    if (flag_groupadded){

                        if ([markersGroupArray_ count]>counter){
                            NSMutableArray *groupArray = [markersGroupArray_ objectAtIndex:counter];
                            [groupArray insertObject:photo atIndex:0];
                            [markersGroupArray_ replaceObjectAtIndex:counter withObject:groupArray];
                        }
                    }
                    else if (!flag_groupadded){

                        NSMutableArray * array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:photo, nil];
                        [markersGroupArray_ addObject:array];
                    }

                }

            } // for loop for photoArray



            // display group point


            [mapView clear];

            photoMarkers_ = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

            for (NSArray *array in markersGroupArray_){

                NSLog(@"arry count %d",[array count]);

                NSDictionary *item = [array objectAtIndex:0];

                float coordx = [[item objectForKey:@"coordx"]floatValue];
                float coordy = [[item objectForKey:@"coordy"] floatValue];

                CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(coordx, coordy);

                GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
                marker.position = coord;
                marker.map = mapView;

                [photoMarkers_ addObject:marker];

                marker = nil;


            }



            NSLog(@"markers %@",photoMarkers_);

        } // zoomlevel diffference thersold


    }
```

Comment: Please check this link i want to display marker animation. please see my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23541930/display-spiderfy-leaflet-annotation-mkmapview

Comment: @chings228 Adding comments in your code could have been really helpful for people who will try to understand and use it, nonetheless thank you for having shared your source code with the community.

Comment: @chings228 If you could please put comments in your code it would be really helpful! thanks