# Clustering annotations won't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mapkit, mkannotationview

Today i started to use ADClusterMapView ( https://github.com/applidium/ADClusterMapView ) and studied the example project... so i decided to add the content to my project... every thing was OK no red errors... the simulator turned on and posted a thread... I'm trying to figure out the problem for hours... so maybe you have idea where the problem is...

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

   [ADClusterMapView class];
   NSArray* airports = [Airport allAirports];
   [mapView setAnnotations:airports];
   [mapView setVisibleMapRect:MKMapRectWorld];
}

-(MKAnnotationView*)mapView:(MKMapView *)aMapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {
static NSString* reuseIdentifier = @"airportAnnotation";

    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[Airport class]]) {
        MKAnnotationView* annotationView = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
        if (!annotationView) {
            annotationView = [[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier] autorelease];
            annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
    }
        annotationView.image = ((Airport*)annotation).icon;
        return annotationView;
    }
}


- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(ADClusterMapView *)aMapView viewForClusterAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {
MKAnnotationView * annotationView = (MKAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"ADMapCluster"];
if (!annotationView) {
    annotationView = [[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation
                                            reuseIdentifier:@"ADMapCluster"]
               autorelease];
    annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"circle.png"];
    annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
}
else {
    annotationView.annotation = annotation;
}
    return annotationView;
}
```

the Error in debuger was:

Airports[3489:c07] -[MKMapView setAnnotations:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8095570
Airports[3489:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MKMapView setAnnotations:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8095570'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1945012 0x1275e7e 0x19d04bd 0x1934bbc 0x193494e 0x2b6e 0x29e817 0x29e882 0x1eda25 0x1ee311 0x28db 0x1ba7b7 0x1bada7 0x1bbfab 0x1cd315 0x1ce24b 0x1bfcf8 0x18a0df9 0x18a0ad0 0x18babf5 0x18ba962 0x18ebbb6 0x18eaf44 0x18eae1b 0x1bb7da 0x1bd65c 0x282d 0x2765)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c

Comment: At first, I tried myself to use ADClusterMapView but I finally ended up building my own simple clustering system, inspired by WWDC 2011 presentation. If you want to have a look, check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/20271466/1394534. There are both codes for Google SDK and MapKit

Comment: Than you! Do you have a example project in github or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

`[mapView setAnnotations:airports];` seems to be the problem.
From [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html), only `addAnnotations:`, `addAnnotation:` and their remove equivalent are available. Plus, `annotations` property is `readonly` so `setAnnotations` crashes, normal

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, it's happening because you forgot to change the Custom Class on Identity Inspector (right side Utilities). Simply set the value to ADClusterMapView.