# Display spiderfy leaflet annotation MKMapView

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps-api-3, mapkit

[image]I want to show 100 map points using MKMapView on same lat longs. Please see the [link](http://www.yourmapper.com/demo/spiderfy.htm).

Same thing i want in iphone.

Comment: Please check this link i want to display using spiderfy leafleft animation. http://www.yourmapper.com/demo/spiderfy.htm. When i used normal process the map points are over lapping each other and unable to click particular map point. SO by using spiderfy animation we can achive this. any idea.

Comment: Finally i found solution by using Jquery+HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use 100's of annotation then below is the tutorial which will help you.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/21365/introduction-to-mapkit-in-ios-6-tutorial

In this tutorial if you check the below method it will resolve your issue.

```
(void)plotCrimePositions:(NSData *)responseData {

for (id<MKAnnotation> annotation in _mapView.annotations) {
    [_mapView removeAnnotation:annotation];
}

NSDictionary *root = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:nil];

NSArray *data = [root objectForKey:@"data"];

for (NSArray *row in data) {

    NSNumber * latitude = [[row objectAtIndex:22]objectAtIndex:1];

    NSNumber * longitude = [[row objectAtIndex:22]objectAtIndex:2];

    NSString * crimeDescription = [row objectAtIndex:18];

    NSString * address = [row objectAtIndex:14];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

    coordinate.latitude = latitude.doubleValue;

    coordinate.longitude = longitude.doubleValue;

    MyLocation *annotation = [[MyLocation alloc] initWithName:crimeDescription address:address coordinate:coordinate] ;
    [_mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
}
}
```

Comment: '[_mapView removeAnnotations:_mapview.annotations];' does what your first loop does.

Comment: please check spidefy animation in this link...http://www.yourmapper.com/demo/spiderfy.htm

Comment: When i used normal process the map points are over lapping each other and unable to click particular map point. SO by using spiderfy animation we can achive this. any idea.Please check this link i want to display using spiderfy leafleft animation...  http://www.yourmapper.com/demo/spiderfy.htm  click on map points it will expand.