# GMSMarker Clustering

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

Does anyone have some working example for Marker Clustering for Google Maps on iOS? I tried to find in on official docs from Google but there is nothing. I have an issue with many markers on map that make my map too much slow and device is stuck.

I have reviewed "too many markers" article from google, there are no examples at all.

Thanks for help

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20175605/marker-clustering-with-google-maps-sdk-for-ios

Comment: Please do update this question with an answer if you have found one @Anton..

Comment: We have solved it on server side