# Clustering in Google Maps SDK for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I have been using the google SDK in my iOS app. In which I used to marker for plotting the location.
I have so many markers in a particular, so I have decided to use the clustering concept here.

Please let me know how can use the clustering in google maps sdks. 
Is there any library which can be used for clustering using google maps sdks.

Comment: what do you intend to present to the user after this "clustering" ?

Comment: possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20175605/marker-clustering-with-google-maps-sdk-for-ios