# Cluster markers on Google Maps for iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps

I'm trying to implement some method to create  clusters of points in a map. Does any one have some working solution for this?

Comment: Did you search Google for a tutorial / sample?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clustering Google Maps Markers in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18710189/clustering-google-maps-markers-in-ios)

Comment: I did it and there is no example for it.

Comment: same problem here....did you find any solution?

Comment: Mapbox is an open source maps library. They do clustering. You can checkout the code at their repo: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-ios-sdk and look for their approach.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Marker clustering with google maps SDK for iOS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20175605/marker-clustering-with-google-maps-sdk-for-ios)